# jQuery content slider - No buttons/fade in & out transition

Tags: jquery, slider

Fairly basic question but I am looking for a jQuery content slider, with no buttons just a continuous fade in/out slide through 4 different paragraphs of content.

I have done my searches on Google and cannot seem to find that slider which will do what I want - I was hoping someone on here could recommend one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?? http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

This might be what are you looking for. You can customise your own scroll bar or use one of the multiple options they give you.

I've tried it and it really works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think the NivoSlider is what you're searching for when you want to use images/videos only.

It's available here: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/
and when you scroll down the page, you'll see true/false options for showing the controls.

If you want to use html content, last thing I heard of is that nivoslider isn't capable of that.

So, if you want to use html content inside the slides, try the rhinoslider available here:
http://rhinoslider.com/how-to-use/
On the linked page you could use the demo to match your needs.

A little more info would be nice, though. Should it be responsive and things? What content do you want to display?

Hope this post helps.

Greetings,
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You may try some of these-

http://delicious.com/anupdg/Content+slideshow

Regards

Anup Das Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You can see the options from the link I attached to choose the different transition effects ........

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title>Skitter - Slideshow for anytime!</title>
    <link href="css/skitter.styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.skitter.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            numbers: false,// the thing required no anchoring or navigation
            navigation:false,
            animation: "random",
            velocity:0.2, //velocity of animation
            interval:4000// time gap between the transitions
        };
        $('.box_skitter_large').skitter(options);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="border_box" style="width:200px" >
            <div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large" style="margin-left:152px;margin-top:34px">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#cube"><img src="images/1.jpg" class="cube" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cube</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#cubeRandom"><img src="images/2.jpg" class="cubeRandom" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeRandom</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#block"><img src="images/3.jpg" class="block" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>block</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#cubeStop"><img src="images/4.jpg" class="cubeStop" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeStop</p></div></li>
                    <li><a href="#cubeHide"><img src="images/5.jpg" class="cubeHide" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeHide</p></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

for downloading the js and css files and to see different transition effects visit:
http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/